# JPanel doesn't draw properly

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've posted a few questions without any response. This homework is due in a few days, and I have no idea what's going wrong with this. I'm making a blackjack game, and my goals are really quite simple: I just want to draw some cards on a screen, as well as some labels that tell me what the the score is. The problems are three-fold, and possibly have the same root cause:

1) The component does not draw a background properly. Calling `setBackground` does nothing, and explicitly drawing a rectangle works, but is subsequently overdrawn by the color gray for reasons that entirely escape me.

2)  is that when I call setText on the labels, the new text is drawn OVER the old text, instead of replacing it.

3) I have a function that draws a new card every time the user presses the "Hit" button, it gives them a new card. When the cards recalculate their position, the old ones stay on screen, so you see multiple copies of the same card.

Here's the code in the JPanel subclass that draws everything:

```
package problem5.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import problem5.controller.BlackJackController;
import problem5.model.Card;
import problem5.model.Player;


public class CardPanel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Card> crdCardsOnPanel;
    private final int DEFAULT_PANEL_WIDTH = 600;
    private int nCardHeight = 180;
    private int nCardWidth = 135;
    private int nPanelWidth;
    private int nPanelHeight;
    private int nDeckOffset;
    private int nHeightOffset;
    private int nSecondOffset;
    private int nCardSpaceWidth;
    private int nU;
    private int nSecondPanelVerticalOffset;
    private JButton btnHit;
    private JButton btnStick;
    private JLabel lblPlayerScore;
    private JLabel lblDealerScore;
    private BlackJackController bjc;

    private int nDealerCardXCoords[];
    private int nPlayerCardXCoords[];

    public CardPanel(final BlackJackController bjc) {
        this.bjc = bjc;

        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.green);

        //set button behavior
        btnHit = new JButton("Hit");        
        btnHit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                bjc.dealCard(getPlayer());
            }
        });
        btnStick = new JButton("Stick");

        lblPlayerScore = new JLabel();
        lblDealerScore = new JLabel();

        resize(DEFAULT_PANEL_WIDTH);
        System.out.printf("Bounds: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", 
                getBounds().x, getBounds().y, getBounds().width, getBounds().height);

        add(btnHit);
        add(btnStick);
        add(lblDealerScore);
        add(lblPlayerScore);
    }

    public void addCard(Card crdNew) {
        crdCardsOnPanel.add(crdNew);
    }

    public void setController(BlackJackController bjc) {
        this.bjc = bjc;
    }

    private BlackJackController getController(){
        return this.bjc;
    }

    public void resize(int nNewWidth) {
        nPanelWidth = nNewWidth;
        nU = (int) (nNewWidth/36.0);
        nPanelHeight = nU * 10;
        nDeckOffset = nU;
        nHeightOffset = nU;
        nSecondOffset = nU;
        nCardSpaceWidth = nU * 27;
        nCardHeight = nU * 8;
        nCardWidth = nU * 6;
        nSecondPanelVerticalOffset = nU * 14;

        //set bounds of buttons and labels
        btnHit.setBounds(new Rectangle(nDeckOffset,
                   getPlayerCardViewRectangle().y,
                   nCardWidth, nCardHeight/2));
        btnStick.setBounds(new Rectangle(nDeckOffset,
                   getPlayerCardViewRectangle().y + nCardHeight/2,
                   nCardWidth, nCardHeight/2));

        lblPlayerScore.setBounds(new Rectangle(1*nU, 11*nU, 16*nU, 2*nU));
        lblDealerScore.setBounds(new Rectangle(19*nU, 11*nU, 16*nU, 2*nU));

        //calculate positions of dealer's and player's cards
        calculateDealerCardXCoords();
        calculatePlayerCardXCoords();


        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(nPanelWidth, 24*nU));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(nPanelWidth, 24*nU));

    }

    private void updateLabels() {
        int nPlayerScore = getController().getPlayerScore();
        int nDealerScore = getController().getDealerScore();

        lblPlayerScore.setText(getPlayer().getName() + "'s Score: " + nPlayerScore);
        lblDealerScore.setText("Dealer's Score: "+ nDealerScore);
    }

    public void resize() {
        resize(getBounds().width);
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return getController().getPlayer();
    }

    public Player getDealer() {
        return getController().getDealer();
    }

    private void calculateDealerCardXCoords() {
        int nNumberOfCards = getDealer().getHand().getHandSize();
        int xCoords[] = new int[nNumberOfCards];
        int nOffset;

        if (nNumberOfCards <= 4)
            nOffset = 7*nU;
        else
            nOffset = nCardSpaceWidth/nNumberOfCards;

        for (int i=0; i<nNumberOfCards; i++) {
            xCoords[i] = i*nOffset + nDeckOffset;
        }

        nDealerCardXCoords = xCoords;
    }

    private void calculatePlayerCardXCoords() {
        int nNumberOfCards = getPlayer().getHand().getHandSize();
        int xCoords[] = new int[nNumberOfCards];
        int nOffset;

        if (nNumberOfCards <= 4)
            nOffset = 7*nU;
        else
            nOffset = (nCardSpaceWidth-nCardWidth)/nNumberOfCards;

        for (int i=0; i<nNumberOfCards; i++) {
            xCoords[i] = i*nOffset;
        }

        nPlayerCardXCoords = xCoords;
    }

    public Rectangle getDealerCardViewRectangle() {
        Rectangle rectReturn = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle currentView = getBounds();
        rectReturn.x = currentView.x + nDeckOffset;
        rectReturn.y = currentView.y + nHeightOffset;
        rectReturn.height = nCardHeight;
        rectReturn.width = nCardSpaceWidth;
        return rectReturn;
    }

    public Rectangle getPlayerCardViewRectangle() {
        Rectangle rectReturn = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle currentView = getBounds();
        rectReturn.x = currentView.x + nDeckOffset + 8*nU;
        rectReturn.y = currentView.y + nHeightOffset + nSecondPanelVerticalOffset;
        rectReturn.height = nCardHeight;
        rectReturn.width = nCardSpaceWidth;
        return rectReturn;
    }

    public void updateScreen() {
        resize();
        updateLabels();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //draw background
        g.setColor(new Color(15,125,1));
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 36*nU, 24*nU);

        //draw dealer's cards
        for (int i=0; i<nDealerCardXCoords.length; i++) {
            g.drawImage(getDealer().getHand().getCards().get(i).getImage(),
                    nDealerCardXCoords[i] + getDealerCardViewRectangle().x, getDealerCardViewRectangle().y, 
                    nCardWidth, nCardHeight, null, null);
        }

        //draw player's cards
        for (int i=0; i<nPlayerCardXCoords.length; i++) {
            g.drawImage(getPlayer().getHand().getCards().get(i).getImage(),
                    nPlayerCardXCoords[i] + getPlayerCardViewRectangle().x, getPlayerCardViewRectangle().y, 
                    nCardWidth, nCardHeight, null, null);
        }

//      lblDealerScore.repaint();
//      lblPlayerScore.repaint();
    }


}
```

And here's a screenshot of what's going on:
http://s10.postimage.org/3kokr17o9/Screen_Shot_2012_11_24_at_6_31_39_PM.png

Comment: Can you minimize your code to the least reproducible piece?

Answer (score 3):

OK, the problem was that I didn't put the line `super.paintComponent(g)` in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function of `CardPanel`. So, always do this! :)

Comment: +1 for *"So, always do this"* and not making me repeat my self ;)